# Remove application name and servlet mapping from URL

Tags: apache, tomcat, redirect, servlets

I am using Apache httpd and proxying requests to my Tomcat server where my application WARs are deployed.

Let's say I have application `App` and servlet URL pattern `/servlet1` and domain name `abc.com`. So, when I forward request from my `ROOT.war` servlet to `/App/servlet1`, my URL changes to `abc.com/App/servlet1`, but I would prefer `abc.com` for a better user experience.

I know I could do this by re-nameing `App` to `ROOT.war` but that is not an option for me, as we already have a `ROOT.war` for another application.

Is it possible to rewrite `abc.com/App/servlet1` to `abc.com` other then `ROOT.war`? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: How would you know if a request is directed to your ROOT.war application or to your App.war application, if they both share the same URL path?

Comment: In my case, request to domain lands to our ROOT.war and we have separate war that validates few things. So a servlet from ROOT.war sends 302 redirect request to servlet in App.war. App.war does all validation/checks and redirect request back to ROOT.war. So in this case, i do not want to show the URL change in browser to user. It should always be abc.com. I am not much familiar with apache configurations, is it possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to merge your `ROOT` and `App` applications together into a single application.

No servlet contains is going to be able to detect when *some* URLs should go to one application and others should go to another without some obvious mapping strategy. The servlet specification uses mandates the use of URL prefixes (context paths) to differentiate between deployed web applications: you cannot mix them together unless they are in fact the same application.

There are very very ugly ways to do this, but those techniques end up opening up a whole lot of headaches and continued hacks just to get around what sounds like a senseless requirement: making URLs pretty. Nobody cares how pretty a URL is. Make sure that `example.com` takes the user to the right place and don't worry about any of the rest of it.